# How to parse a JSON whose field name is a value in Go?

Tags: json, rest, go, decode

I receive from a service a JSON that has this format.

```
{
    "result": {
        "bn05deh7jsm86gtlg2l0C": [
            {
                "index_name": "BASE",
                "index_value": 4081512,
                "timestamp": "2019-11-05T13:20:00Z",
                "op_id": "A0000000001"
            },
            ...
        ],
        "bn05deh7jsm86gtlg2lgC": [
            {
                "index_name": "BASE",
                "index_value": 4728633,
                "timestamp": "2019-11-05T13:20:00Z",
                "op_id": "A0000000001"
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

What I need is to transform it to an array of object like []Measure:

```
type Measure struct {
    IndexName    string    `json:"index_name"`
    IndexValue   uint32    `json:"index_value"`
    Timestamp    time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    OperationID  string    `json:"op_id"`
    Guid         string    `json:"guid"`
}
```

Where `Guid` should have value `bn05deh7jsm86gtlg2l0C`, `bn05deh7jsm86gtlg2lgC`, etc.

Here is my code:

```
url := "https://myurl.com"
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if req != nil {
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return nil
}
var measures []Measure
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&measures)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decode to a type that matches the structure of the data:

```
var d struct{ Result map[string][]Measure }
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&d)
```

Convert that data to the desired result:

```
var measures []Measure
for k, vs := range d.Result {
    for _, v := range vs {
        v.Guid = k
        measures = append(measures, v)
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zqY66iKEWrp)

Comment: @Adrian: Oh, right. :/

Comment: There is a typo in the first code block though, `Decode(&measures)` should be `Decode(&d)` to suit the example.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this with plain encoding/json. Marstall into a map[string]Measure